# Crossdomain ajax request to controller with requireAjaxRequest()

Tags: ajax, controller

I make request from my localhost(gulp server) to example domain in to VerifyPassword controller. When i make request without `headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}`, It comes as expected 400 Bad request

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://example/index.php/actions/users/verifyPassword',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $data,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success(data, response) {
            console.log(data, response);
        },
        error(data, response) {
            console.log(response, data);
        }
});
```

When i make request with `headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}` comes response `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example/index.php/actions/users/verifyPassword. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`, and are not sent cookies. Done OPTIONS preflight request without cookies and server comes 302 and redirect to `example/login`.
How To be?

---

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/4945-yiiapp-request-isajaxrequest/

Comment: Sounds like you need to set some access control headers? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33645878/684

Comment: No, it has long been set in htaccess.

Comment: try setting `crossDomain: true,` as well

Comment: No Brad, I tried does not help, the server most likely does not correctly handle a request preflight

Comment: Does it work if you post to a controller action that allows anonymous access? Pretty sure the issue is that there isn't a valid authenticated session for the domain you're posting to.

Comment: In a preflight request not passed session and cookies, and  why then are redirected to login

Comment: where i can create issue? Why on response headers added `Location: http://example/login`, even though i send session?

Comment: it can not because of the time difference? The logs all 3 hours earlier than the locale. While I was putting timezone on craft settings. In response the server returns a date for 3 hours early

Answer (score 1):

Looking further into the problem, I've found that the page tries to do a post request to the other domain. It calls upon the action function in the `UsersController.php` file (`Location: /craft/app/controllers/`)

But because the user isn't logged in on the other domain and anonymous access isn't allowed for this action. You get redirected to /login to login on that domain.

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/12268/635

The developers managed to solve this problem? This applies to almost all controllers require session.