# Control Panel freezes due to Access Control Checks?

Tags: control-panel, error-message

Basically, I have no clue what this means?  But, I am unable to edit any entries in Control Panel -- everything times out after I try to save and/or return to the main entries page.

`[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mysite.com/index.php/nc3/actions/users/getAuthTimeout?dontExtendSession=1 due to access control checks.
    send (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4:15971)
    ajax (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4:11523)
    checkAuthTimeout (craft.js:3:22301)
    f (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:3704)`

I don't know for sure, but the error seems to be connected to adding `siteURL` to `general.php`.

But, (and I am a noob) it was set to http://www.mysite.com.   which is exactly what appears in CP.   I assume I do not need to list it in both places?

Comment: Are you loading the CP from exactly www.mysite.com?  Or is it mysite.com or another domain/IP?

Comment: Not clear.  I use the full `www.mysite.com` when I go to it.  When it loads it switches to just `mystic.com` - but if I click into the navigation window it shows the full `www...`.    All I know, is the problem cleared once I removed the `siteUrl` from the `general.php` settings.  But, I want the site to be accessible whether I type `mysite.com` or `www.mysite.com`.

Comment: You're running into this: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/431/57

Comment: I don't know. I followed every step.  My url settings appear consistent everywhere, yet I am still experiencing this problem.